# How to handle speed dial actions using material ui?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, speed-dial

I have three actions supporting my SpeedDialAction, however when I try to log the event of the individual actions onClick, I get undefined.

I have tried using different functions as actions, also tried arrow function syntax in the method call

```
onClick={e => action.action(e)}
```

and

```
onClick={action.action}
```

The actions:

```
const actions = [
    { icon: <Add />, name: 'Product', action: handleDialogOpen },
    { icon: <Add />, name: 'Addon', action: handleDialogOpen },
    { icon: <Label />, name: 'Tag', action: handleDialogOpen }
  ]
```

The SpeedDial:

```
<SpeedDial
          ariaLabel='SpeedDial example'
          className={classes.speedDial}
          icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}
          onBlur={handleClose}
          onClick={handleClick}
          onClose={handleClose}
          onFocus={handleOpen}
          onMouseEnter={handleOpen}
          onMouseLeave={handleClose}
          open={open}
        >
          {actions.map(action => (
            <SpeedDialAction
              tooltipOpen
              key={action.name}
              icon={action.icon}
              tooltipTitle={action.name}
              onClick={action.action}
            />
          ))}
        </SpeedDial>
```

handleDialogOpen simply tries to log the event

I expect the output being an event object, not undefined.

Answer (score 8):

You can define an extra object item in `actions` array.

```
const actions = [
    { icon: <Add />, name: 'Product', action: handleDialogOpen, operation: 'product'},
    { icon: <Label />, name: 'Tag', action: handleDialogOpen , operation: 'tag' }
  ]
```

Now you need to call a handler function and pass the `operation` value as a parameter:

```
//handler function
 function handleClick (e,operation){
   e.preventDefault();
   if(operation=="product"){
     // do something 
   }else if(operation=="tag"){
     //do something else
   }
   setOpen(!open);// to close the speed dial, remove this line if not needed.
 };
```

```
<SpeedDial
          ariaLabel='SpeedDial example'
          className={classes.speedDial}
          icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}
          onBlur={handleClose}
          onClick={handleClick}
          onClose={handleClose}
          onFocus={handleOpen}
          onMouseEnter={handleOpen}
          onMouseLeave={handleClose}
          open={open}
        >
          {actions.map(action => (
            <SpeedDialAction
              tooltipOpen
              key={action.name}
              icon={action.icon}
              tooltipTitle={action.name}
              onClick={(e) => {
                      handleClick(e.action.operation)
                 }}
            />
          ))}
        </SpeedDial>
```

Comment: Multiple `onClick` handlers are confusing here - specifically it's the `SpeedDialAction` and should be `action.operation` passed in the handler, not `actions.operation`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code on Typescript based on Material UI 5.13.14 https://mui.com/material-ui/react-speed-dial/

Optional: Define menuOptions

```
enum menuOptions {
  'MENU',
  'COMPARE',
  'SHARE',
}
```

Define your actions. Make shure to add the operation field.

```
const actions = [
  { icon: <List />, name: 'Menú', operation: menuOptions.MENU },
  { icon: <Compare />, name: 'Comparar', operation: menuOptions.COMPARE },
  { icon: <Share />, name: 'Compartir', operation: menuOptions.SHARE },
]
```

Now create the SpeedDial component. Make sure to add onClick={(e) => { handleClick(e, action.operation) }} in SpeedDialAction

```
  return (
    <>
      <SpeedDial
        ariaLabel="Menu"
        sx={{
          position: 'fixed',
          bottom: 20,
          right: 20,
        }}
        onClick={handleOpen}
        open={open}
        icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}
        direction="up"
      >
        {actions.map((action) => (
          <SpeedDialAction
            key={action.name}
            icon={action.icon}
            tooltipTitle={action.name}
            onClick={(e) => {
              handleClick(e, action.operation)
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </SpeedDial>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Also you may do this. Set your handler that closes your modal. And in the onClick, set an anonymous activating the action function and closing the modal. :

```
const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);


<SpeedDial
      ariaLabel='SpeedDial example'
      className={classes.speedDial}
      icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}
      onBlur={handleClose}
      onClick={handleClick}
      onClose={handleClose}
      onFocus={handleOpen}
      onMouseEnter={handleOpen}
      onMouseLeave={handleClose}
      open={open}
    >
      {actions.map(action => (
        <SpeedDialAction
          tooltipOpen
          key={action.name}
          icon={action.icon}
          tooltipTitle={action.name}
          onClick={() => {
            action.action()
            handleClose()  }}
        />
      ))}
    </SpeedDial>
```